# My Terminal's background color desyncs after too many new lines

Tags: c++, terminal, colors, newline, visual-glitch

Like I said in my title, after 3 or so iterations of this code, the text background starts to bug out. It kind of looks like how Source games act out of bounds/with no skybox.

> I'm using VS 2017, also if it helps I'm on a display resolution of 1280 X 768.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;
int x;
int main()
{
    labelSTART:
    HANDLE hConsole = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, 6+2*16);
    
    cout << "This is as far as this goes.\nGo back?  0-NO  1-YES\n";
    cin >> x;
    if (x == 1) {
        SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, 1+5*16);
        cout << "Going back...\nProceed with caution!";
        cout << "\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n";
        goto labelSTART;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[third iteration of the program and it's consequences](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HCjmt.png)

I am making a game in the Terminal and want to use colors and to fully refresh the screen every frame. The problem is that after 2 or so screens the unused space of the terminal gets filled in with the last used background color and messes everything up.

Comment: Terminals are know to be buggy and with a lot of interpretation on how to manage things (also because in past it was not easy to find documents, and so interpretation diverged). Windows entered also late on the "old style console".